# limit of rows for a healthy mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I read somewhere that there is a [guiding principle](http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-mysql-1-million-rows-golden-rule-1648.html) to limit the number of rows in tables to below 1 million.  I was wondering if this was true. For a project I have I will roughly have tables with 10,000 rows, 40,000 rows, 160,000 rows, and 100,000 rows respectively. What performance could I expect on a 4 core, 8 GB machine for this? (I know some people achieved 20k requests per second)

Comment: Is there a way I could actually load dummy data to test this?

Comment: Sure - look at the schema for the table that you expect to fill with a million rows. You can ignore the nullable columns for obvious reasons. For non-null columns, make up some data that suits the column. Where you need an incrementing or other unique value, just use a counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one million number is bogus. I've run MySQL instances with tables that have 20 million rows and over a dozen columns. Queries weren't fast, but the application was offline data processing and performance was more than adequate.

You should benchmark queries on your own system to determine its performance. I can't tell you anything about a system with "4 cores, 8 gb" beyond the fact that 8 GB is a good starting point for a big database server (you should be able to keep your indexes in memory, and smaller tables may also fit in memory). Four cores could be plenty of CPU, but it might not be. It depend entirely on what sort of cores they are.

You also shouldn't ignore disk performance, particularly if your tables won't fit in RAM. I think the machine I had 20m rows on had a RAID 1+0 array of 15k RPM disks.

But don't take my comments to mean that you need more RAM, more CPUs or faster disks. Run some benchmarks on your own system. Make sure your system has an appropriate schema for your queries. Make sure you have as few subqueries and views (results aren't indexed) as possible. Make sure your tables are properly indexed. Then look at your performance and hardware.

Comment: In addition to this, check how you're joining.  It's pretty easy to get some _temporary_ tables that have huge rowcounts, if you do a full cartesian join.

Comment: yes, will do, I just wish there was a way I could add dummy data for a quick benchmark.

Comment: Just write a bit of code to generate dummy data for your rows, and then insert away until you have enough. This is a good practice for your integration tests as well. You do have integration tests, right?

Comment: yes I do integration tests :). Im actually a front end guy, but this is the first side project where Im taking the mysql side completely

Comment: Do you understand how to generate some dummy data?